# Obtain image from 3 one dimensional numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have three 1D numpy arrays of the same dimension N, say x, y and z. The x and y arrays stand for Carthesian coordinates and the z array stands for the values at those specific coordinates.

I would like to obtain an image where the color/intensity at a point (x,y) is given by the value in the array z.

In order to do that I've looked into `imshow` which makes images from 2D arrays. In order to use `imshow` I need to convert my z array into a 2D array. I found that `meshgrid` can convert my 1D x and y arrays to 2D via the command:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y).
```

However, I could not find how to convert my z 1D array to a 2D array that corresponds to the Carthesian coordinates from above.

What I'm after is essentially shown in this example

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
>>> y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
>>> xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
>>> z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
>>> h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
>>> plt.show()
```

But in my case the z array is given and it represents the samples of a function z = f(x,y).

Here is an example of what I have. This is from a csv file with the following:

```
x, y, z
-10,4,30
-4,3,20
10,10,12
-11.5,3,-33.2
-5,0,23
-4,-2,8
0,2,1
5,12,42
11.2,5,23
```

Comment: Unless you provide some reproducible code, it is extremely difficult for readers to help you. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if z has a length equal to length(x) * length(y) as it seems, did you try numpy.reshape?

Comment: @GuilhemL. z has the same dimension as x and y.

Comment: @Sheldore You want me to add the `linspace` commands for x,y and z? There is no other code than the 3 1D numpy arrays that have the same dimension

Comment: Do `x` and `y` define the coordinates independent of each other? In that case, if `z` has the same shape as `x` and `y`, how is `z` supposed to represent a two-dimensional image? What does `z` represent anyway? It should be of shape `(len(x) * len(y),)` or the `x` and `y` should behave already as if they were coming from `meshgrid`. In any case the solution is to `z.reshape`.

Comment: @Tiberiu : Yes, at least add the three input 1d arrays/lists

Comment: @a_guest Think of the 1D array z as a sampled function z = f(x,y) where x and y are indeed independent of eachother and are just Carthesian coordinates.

Comment: @Sheldore Hopefully I made it clearer now

Comment: @Tiberiu Then your sampling is incorrect since you should invoke that function with the grid coordinates coming from `meshgrid`. Then `z` will be two-dimensional to start with and you won't have that problem. In case `x` and `y` already come from `meshgrid` (i.e. they are not independent) then you can just `z.reshape(len(x), len(y))`.

Comment: @Tiberiu : You need to reshape your z array to a 2d array. How you need to reshape depends on the order of elements in z. To what values and in which order do they correspond to x and y. Why don't you just share 3 sample 1d arrays of let's say 9 elements each? That will save your time and others' time in chasing the unknown

Comment: You can also try something like `tricontourf(x, y, z)`. That way you don't need to construct 2D arrays.

Comment: @Sheldore It seems you are right since the x and y data do go through a range and then just repeat, however the range and the width of the steps is not consistent.

Comment: Are you looking for an interpolation?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Eventually, yes.